# How to find day light time saving is active and save time in SQL for UK?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am looking to save current UK time and problem is they have two timezone GMT and BST accordingly day saving light ?

I am saving time in SQL date time column from mobile app and SQL server. I am insert time using SQL.

Comment: Store all your dates in a common timezone e.g. UTC. Then when you need to display it to the user, convert it to the correct timezone for that user. You can know whether an incoming date from a UK user (and other countries which use DST) is a summertime date or not by comparing it with the published dates for the start and end of DST usage. Or maybe the date incoming will have timezone info attached already. Depends on how the date is being generated I guess